# Checkbox inside a link behaves wrong when Bootstrap toggling is added

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3

There are three content blocks and I'd like to enable/disable them with the Bootstrap's `data-*` "tools". The control elements should be `checkbox`es. When a content block is displayed, its `checkbox` should be `checked`.

**summary**

The problem is, that the `checkbox` inside links are not working as expected (starting to change the state only after the second click), after adding the Bootstrap behavior to the wrapping `a` tags.

The code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/automatix/jsL3dx1w/5/).

**long version**

So first of all I created the content blocks and the controls without functionality (and gave them some styles):

```
<div class="col-xs-12" id="select-panel">
    <div class="col-lg-12" id="filter-bar">
        <div>
            <a href="#containerFoo">
                <label class="btn btn-primary" id="filterFoo">
                    <input type="checkbox" checked autocomplete="off">
                    <span class="text-label">foo</span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span>
                </label>
            </a>
            <a href="#containerBar">
                <label class="btn btn-primary" id="filterBar">
                    <input type="checkbox" checked autocomplete="off">
                    <span class="text-label">bar</span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span>
                </label>
            </a>
            <a href="#containerBuz">
                <label class="btn btn-primary" id="filterBuz">
                    <input type="checkbox" checked autocomplete="off">
                    <span class="text-label">buz</span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>
                </label>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>&nbsp;</div>

<div class="panel panel-default in" id="containerFoo">foo</div>
<div class="panel panel-default in" id="containerBar">bar</div>
<div class="panel panel-default in" id="containerBuz">buz</div>
```

The `checkbox`es are behaving as expected. Now the actual functionality needs to be added. The the `A` tags were extended as follows:

```
...
<a href="#containerFoo" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="containerFoo">
    ...
</a>
<a href="#containerBar" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="containerBar">
    ...
</a>
<a href="#containerBuz" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="containerBuz">
    ...
</a>
...
```

Now the toggling is working. But the `checkbox`es are always `checked`. Well, after it I also extended the `DIV` wrapper around the control `checkbox`es:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
```

Now the `checkbox`es are behaving ever stranger. On the first click the `checkbox` remains on (`checked`). An from the second click on the same `checkbox` the behavior becomes normal: the state gets changed on every click.

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

**How to get `checkbox`es inside links working correctly, when Bootstrap toggling is used?**

Comment: label, input wrapped inside a link is not a good idea, which is the one supposed to catch the click event ?   ... remove the checked attribute from input

Comment: If I do so, I'll need to synchronize the `checkbox` with the  toggling logic executed by Bootstrap. It  might cause a lot of needless effort.

Comment: up to you, but still label/checkbox wrap inside a link is not valid  ... again to which should go  the click event even if you desagree with the W3C validator  ( https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea ) ?

Comment: Thank you for the hint! Yes, It's actually not valid. Hm... OK, for me it's a killer argument. Means, I definitely have to find another solution. E.g. your advice or checkbox als glyphicon or something else.

Comment: I would keep the link and drop the form elements. the checkbox can be drawn from a pseudo holding a checmark or not . ( https://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=check )

Comment: i guess it is your turn to be offline. here is the idea https://jsfiddle.net/jsL3dx1w/7/ if that answers the question ;)

Comment: @G-Cyr Thank you very much! I took your solution and edited it a bit. The principle is still the same, but implemented with glyphicons: https://jsfiddle.net/automatix/jsL3dx1w/41/ Feel free to post it as answer, I will accept it.

Comment: it works and looks great, well done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep the link and drop the form elements.

the checkbox can be drawn from a pseudo holding a checkmark or not.

here is the basic idea : https://jsfiddle.net/jsL3dx1w/7/

```css
#filter-bar {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: right;
}

#filter-bar * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#filter-bar a,
#filter-bar a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a[data-toggle]:before {
  display:inline-block;
  content:'\2713';
  border:solid 1px white;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 2px black, 0 0 1px black;
  line-height:0.6em;
  color:darkblue;
  width:0.8em;height:0.8em;
}
a[data-toggle].collapsed:before {content:''}
#filter-bar  {
    outline: none;
    border: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#filter-bar  span{
    margin: 5px 5px 0 5px;
    outline: 0;
}

#filter-bar .btn:active,
#filter-bar .btn.active {
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

#containerFoo,
#filter-bar #filterFoo {
    background: #f5a623;
}

#containerBar,
#filter-bar #filterBar {
    background: #50c14e;
}

#containerBuz,
#filter-bar #filterBuz {
    background: #d21f31;
}

.clear {
    float: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-xs-12" id="select-panel">
<div class="col-lg-12" id="filter-bar">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <a href="#containerFoo" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="containerFoo"class="btn btn-primary" id="filterFoo">
            <span class="text-label">foo</span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span>
        </a>
        <a href="#containerBar" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="containerBar" class="btn btn-primary" id="filterBar">
            <span class="text-label">bar</span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span>
        </a>
        <a href="#containerBuz" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="containerBuz" class="btn btn-primary" id="filterBuz">
            <span class="text-label">buz</span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div>&nbsp;</div>

<div class="panel panel-default in" id="containerFoo">
foo
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default in" id="containerBar">
bar
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default in" id="containerBuz">
buz
</div>
```

> automatix [wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52128081/checkbox-inside-a-link-behaves-wrong-when-bootstrap-toggling-is-added?noredirect=1#comment91229051_52128081)
>
> I took your solution and edited it a bit. The principle is still the same, but implemented with glyphicons: http://jsfiddle.net/automatix/jsL3dx1w/41 .